# Powershell button Add_Click() to connect to Exchange Online

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I am trying to create a simple GUI to connect to Exchange Online with PowerShell. When clicking the button the Office 365 credential prompt should pop up. This does not happen and I can't understand why. What am I missing? When replacing the "Connect-ExchangeOnline" with "Connect-Msolservice". The Prompt does show up.

```
Add-Type -Assembly System.Windows.Forms



$main_form = New-Object Windows.Forms.Form
$main_form.Text = "GUI for Exchange Online"
$main_form.Width = 600
$main_form.Height = 400
$main_form.AutoSize = $true



$label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label.Text = "Connect to O365"
$label.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(0,10)
$label.Autosize = $true
$main_form.Controls.Add($label) 


$Button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button 
$Button.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size (100,5)
$Button.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,23)
$Button.Text = "Connect"

$main_form.Controls.Add($Button)

$Button.Add_Click{
    Connect-ExchangeOnline 
    
} 




$main_form.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: Maybe a dumb question, but the module ExchangePowershell is installed? Do you have anything in your console? If not, maybe the connexion is working fine and due to some SSO you are logged without any prompt.

Comment: Yeah, should have mentioned if I use the connect-exchangeonline cmdlet it works fine on its own. When using it in the script the cmdlet runs, the prompt for credentials do not pop up.

Comment: Have you tried this on another system. It works for me. I used PowerShell ISE to run this.

Comment: `Connect-ExchangeOnline` can re-use previous auth. E.g. you run `Connect-AzureAD`, type your credentials, and then run `Connect-ExchangeOnline` it will not ask creds the second time

Comment: Is the example correct? Seems to be missing brackets: `$Button.Add_Click({ Connect-ExchangeOnline })`